# How to make "ad-hoc" API call to Rails server in the context of default Rails testing framework

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, minitest, end-to-end

How do I make an "ad-hoc" API call to a Rails server in the context of the default Rails testing framework (minitest using Selenium for the end-to-end tests)?

I am working on a Rails app with views that contain client-side JavaScript that make API calls back to the server. The app is designed so that the only API calls should be coming from the web browser. (Is "API calls" the right term for what the JavaScript is doing? Are there separate terms for (a) background data requests from JavaScript running in a web browser and (b) data requests made by external applications such as a mobile app or command line interface? For what I'm working on right now, I'm specifically concerned about (a). I know that at a high level these are the same thing; but, the details of securing the two types of requests differ slightly.)

I would like to write some end-to-end tests that verify that a user can't access/modify another user's data by issuing requests to the server that aren't generated by my application's JavaScript code.

The main challenge is that issuing such "malicious"/"fake" server requests would require me to have access to both (a) the session cookie and (b) the CSRF token. How do I do that?

1. Is there a way for the Ruby test code to use Selenium to obtain them from the browser? Or,
2. Should I use Selenium to instruct the browser to execute the "custom" Javascript I want to make sure my server responds correctly to?  Or,
3. Should I skip the browser for these tests and simply issue a series of HTTP requests directly from the Ruby code? (This seems to be the more straightforward of the two, except for having to manage the session cookie and CSRF tokens "by hand".)

Or is there a simpler option "4" that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Your app exposes multiple API endpoints to the world. Fundamentally there is no difference between them. Some are used by others, some are used by your app, but all of them need to have consistent authentication and authorization to make  sure your app is secure. As a result, you shouldn't test security of your app through the frontend/selenium, but have a set of request specs minitest. In most app I work on each endpoint (each controller action) will be tested individually to make sure it's protected from unauthorized access.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and it's hard to answer everything without writing a book. [Rails Guides - Securing Rails Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) is a good starting point, but it doesn't cover API-only apps much. This article from [Okta](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/20/rails-guide-securing-api) should give you an idea how to secure an API with JWT tokens, you don't need to use Okta to follow examples shown there.

Comment: For API calls we generally don't use session cookies and definitely not CSRF tokens (where should they come from in an API?). It bothers me a bit when you say `the details of securing the two types of requests differ slightly` because while it may make sense for your app at the moment, it generally isn't a best practice. Unfortunately I know too little about your project to make definitive statements.

Comment: My "API" calls are all from client-side Javascript, so they have access to the CSRF token sent by Rails when displaying a view.  That works for now.  You are right: If the app grows and needs to support non-web based clients, I'll probably have to rewrite the server. That's OK, because by that point, I'm sure I'll find a dozen other things I should have done differently :)

Comment: Thanks for the book/article references.  You are correct: Those are what I really need; but, asking for references like that is against the guidelines.